# PHP Use Variable defined in header.php within another file

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to use a geoplugin (that code works) but I may wish to use the output in multiple locations. Because of this I've taken the code and added it to the header.php file and called the variable within my theme/inc/partials/header-contact.php. But the value is not displaying:

**header-contact.php**

```
<div class="head-contact">
    <?php $details = get_field('options_company_details', 'options');
    global $telephoneNumber; global $telephoneLink;?>
    <span class="phone"><a href="tel:<?php echo $telephoneLink;?>" title="Call Us" onclick="myAjax();" class="gtagc2c"><span class="phone-mob"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i></span><span class="tnumber"></span><?php echo $telephoneNumber;?></a></span>
    <p class="tagline"><?php echo $details['options_tagline'];?></p>
</div>
```

**header.php**

```
<?php include_once(get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/inc/geolocation.php');?>
```

**var_dump in header-contact.php**

```
NULL
```

**var_dump in header.php**

```
NULL
```

**geolocation.php**

```
function getUserIP() {
    $client  = @$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    $forward = @$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    $remote  = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

    if(filter_var($client, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP)){$ip = $client;}
    elseif(filter_var($forward, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP)){$ip = $forward; }
    else { $ip = $remote; } return $ip;
} $user_ip = getUserIP();

$details = get_field('options_company_details', 'options');
$telephoneNumber = $details['options_telephone'];

$getGeoArray = unserialize(file_get_contents('http://www.geoplugin.net/php.gp?ip='.$user_ip.''));

if(in_array($getGeoArray['geoplugin_city'], $lincolnshire)){$telephoneNumber = 'NUMBER';}
elseif(in_array($getGeoArray['geoplugin_city'], $rutland)){$telephoneNumber = 'NUMBER';}
elseif(in_array($getGeoArray['geoplugin_city'], $northamptonshire)){$telephoneNumber = 'NUMBER';}
elseif(in_array($getGeoArray['geoplugin_city'], $norfolk)){$telephoneNumber = 'NUMBER';}
elseif(in_array($getGeoArray['geoplugin_city'], $cambridgeshire)){$telephoneNumber = 'NUMBER';}
elseif(in_array($getGeoArray['geoplugin_city'], $buckinghamshire)){$telephoneNumber = 'NUMBER';}
elseif(in_array($getGeoArray['geoplugin_city'], $bedfordshire)){$telephoneNumber = 'NUMBER';}
elseif(in_array($getGeoArray['geoplugin_city'], $hertfordshire)){$telephoneNumber = 'NUMBER';}
elseif(in_array($getGeoArray['geoplugin_city'], $essex)){$telephoneNumber = 'NUMBER';}
elseif(in_array($getGeoArray['geoplugin_city'], $leicestershire)){$telephoneNumber = $details['options_telephone'];}
$telephoneLink = str_replace(' ', '', $telephoneNumber);
```

*I've removed the variables used in the `in_array()` just to save question length.*

**var_dump in geolaction.php**

```
NUMBER
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using `$_SESSION[]` not quite sure if this is the best way to do this but it works so I am happy:

```
$_SESSION['phonenumber'] = $telephoneNumber;
$_SESSION['phonenumberLink'] = $telephoneLink;

echo $_SESSION['phonenumber'];
echo $_SESSION['phonenumberLink'];
```

Answer (score 0):

This is untested but this may work if called with `wp_head` or `init`. This might make the `global` keyword work in the template parts.

```
// functions.php

// load at wp_head
add_action('wp_head', function() {
    include_once(get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/inc/geolocation.php');
});

// or

add_action('init', function() {
    include_once(get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/inc/geolocation.php');
});
```

Then you don't need to include it in your header file or have to use sessions.